# Changing the exposed variable name for secrets in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

does someone knows how can I change a secret environment exposed variable name? (like in secret manager I have the secret `my-secret` and I want it to be exposed as `MY_SECRET` for my cloud function), with the `gcloud` command this is possible with the `set-secret` argument, but I cant get it to work with the firebase syntax/command.

Does someone knows how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can [read secrets using the SDK provided by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret_parameters) at runtime, the Firebase CLI doesn't let you work with them.  Your only other options are listed in the [environment documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

Maybe you could file a feature request for that on the [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) GitHub.